TypeScript don't resolve the correct type
I am creating an event emitter. I use a generic type to associate each event type with the correct function signature. I would like to transfer all the args, sent to emit(), to the corresponding callback. TypeScript resolve the type of args[0] as undefined | something but args[0] is either undefined or something, not undefined | something.
Here is my code:

type NodeEventTypes = "transaction" | "lostSync" | "sync";
type IssuerEventTypes = "tickSize" | "transferRate";

type EventCallbackMap<T extends NodeEventTypes | IssuerEventTypes> = T extends "transaction" ? (tx: string) => void : () => void;


class EventEmitter<EventTypes extends NodeEventTypes | IssuerEventTypes>
{
    private eventCallback: { [T in EventTypes]?: Array<EventCallbackMap<T>> };


    constructor()
    {
        this.eventCallback = {};
    }


    on<T extends EventTypes>(eventType: T, callback: EventCallbackMap<T>): void
    {
        if (this.eventCallback[eventType] === undefined)
            this.eventCallback[eventType] = [];

        this.eventCallback[eventType].push(callback);
    }


    emit<T extends EventTypes>(eventType: T, ...args: Parameters<EventCallbackMap<T>>)
    {
        if (this.eventCallback[eventType])
            this.eventCallback[eventType].forEach(callback => callback(...args));
    }
}

The error is error TS2556: A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter. and can be:
error TS2345: Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.

    this.eventCallback[eventType].forEach(callback => callback(args[0]));

Searched solutions with ai and Google, and modified a lot of lines in my project. Also tried to cast.

The problem is using the conditional type. TS doesn't infer a proper callback type until you provide a real event parameter so the result of the conditional type is a union of callbacks. Parameters can't handle this union seems.
Just use a different approach with typing the parameters directly:
Playground
type NodeEventTypes = "transaction" | "lostSync" | "sync";
type IssuerEventTypes = "tickSize" | "transferRate";

type AllEventTypes = NodeEventTypes | IssuerEventTypes;

type MakeEventArgMap<T extends {[K in AllEventTypes ]?: any[]}>= {
  [K in Exclude<AllEventTypes , keyof T>]: []
} & T;

type EventArgMap<T extends AllEventTypes > = MakeEventArgMap<{
  transaction: [tx: string]
}>[T];

type EventCallbackMap<T extends AllEventTypes > = (...args: EventArgMap<T>) => void;


Thank you for your response. I had noticed that conditional type could cause strange problems and I have confirmation of this now.
